# Why nth-of-type works that way

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is sample html, which I think should colour every even paragraph in red, but in reality colours the odd ones.

```css
.level1 .level3:nth-of-type(even) p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <div class="unrelated"></div>
    <div class="level3">
      <p>The first paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="level3">
      <p>The second paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="level3">
      <p>The third paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="level3">
      <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does it seem to work like nth-child?

** EDIT ** 
Second example:

```css
.text:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id="A">unrelated</p>
<p id="B" class='text'>The first paragraph.</p>
<p id="C" class='text'>The second paragraph.</p>
<p id="D" class='text'>The third paragraph.</p>
<p id="E" class='text'>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Can you explain why it doesn't behave like that in this case?

Comment: Are you counting evens with the index starting at `0`?

Comment: The `nth-of-type` is applied to the `div`s rather than the `p`. Change `<div class="unrelated"></div>` to `<span class="unrelated"></span>` (any tag other than `div`) and you should see the expected result.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney I've edited the question with a second example. Can you explain why it works differently please?

Comment: Thanks. The reason is `:nth-of-type` doesn't look at the class names. It only looks a the element names. *A* is considered the first element of type `p`, *B* is the second, etc.